# CSS3 Filter in edge doesn't work

Tags: css, filter, microsoft-edge, grayscale

Making this site and using `filter: grayscale(100%);` on the photo divs with background image. 
It works everywhere exept in MS Edge.

https://dev.logic4.nl/over-logic4/team/

Tryed to build it without other css styles and that works perfectly:

https://dev.logic4.nl/wp-content/themes/logic4/test.html

Also tryed to strip down my css and when I delete everything exept the grayscale class it works! don't know what i'm doing wrong.

here's the css class + html

```
    .team-photo{
        float: left;
        width: 38%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: top center;
        .transition-lin;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
     }
    <div class="team-photo" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_avatar_url( $author->ID, array('size' => 400)); ?>');"></div>
```

Comment: What does `.transition-lin;` in the middle of your style mean.

Comment: its a made .less call with the output:
`-webkit-transition: 300ms linear all; transition: 300ms linear all; -o-transition: 300ms linear all; -moz-transition: 300ms linear all;`

I Deleted the test page etc... sry for that still no "grayscale".. weird thing is its working in the footer logo's.